# Combine Phonegap along with native code

Tags: cordova

If I decide to use phonegap framework to make my app be avaliable for many mobile platforms. Is there possibility to combine this with native approach/code (Android, iOS, Windows code) ?

For example If I work with Android and, by some reason, I do not want to use PhoneGap wrapper Api in some piece of my functionality, but use Android one.

Can I create, let's say separate Activity and use Java code there, to use my Camera API?

And what If I want do the same for iOS version?

So, can I use phonegap when I want (where it's possible) and use native code where it's required?

Something like when I code on C and put some ASM injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. They have an amazing way of integrating native and html5 code using plugins, very easy to use and there are tons of them ready to be used.

Check out the documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html).